# Why is Python 2.X division not working as intended even after using float

Tags: python

So after a while of reading through some of my code I kept getting this weird behavior that I simply couldn't get off.

After a while of looking I noticed that the following equation:

```
>>> print 425 / (469 / 100)
```

Would return `106` instead of `~90`. I kept on reading about such behavior in Python and explicitly used `float` to hopefully help with the accuracy a little bit.

```
>>> print 425 / float(469 / 100)
```

Which would now return `106.25` which was not all too helpful. After breaking this up further I simply tried the following:

```
>>> print float(469 / 100)
```

Which to my surprise returned `4.0` and not even `4.1` (rounding). Something that I have encountered with Java but not with Python yet.

Even though I am explicitly using `float` why I am receiving such results? I don't require precise accuracy but wanted it to atleast be between 89 and 91.

This is using Python 2.7

Comment: `469 / 100` is still integer division.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - So I'm guessing I would have to write it like so: `float(469) / float(100)`. Edit: That is indeed correct.. sigh:(.

Comment: You need to divide floating-point numbers, not do integer division and then turn the result into a floating-point number. Just turning one of them into a `float` is sufficient, and you can do it by adding a decimal point: `(469./100)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float` isn't called until the division is performed; the `/` is not affected by the context in which it is called, only by the operands it receives. You need to convert at least one of the operands to a `float`, not the result. For example,

```
>>> print 425 / (469 / float(100))
90.618336887
```

Comment: Or write the numbers (or at least one of them) as float: `print 425 / (469 / 100.0)`

Answer (score 1):

Or put

```
from __future__ import division
```

as the first line of your program.  Then / is floating point division, but you'll have to use // to get ineteger divsion

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 425 / (469 / 100)
90.61833688699359
>>> 425 // (469 // 100)
106
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative :)